# Set Theory: Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are both sets then how can $A \times B = B \times A$ if $A$ does not equal $B$?

Comment: Why do you think $A×B=B×A$?

Answer (score 3):

$A = \emptyset$, $B \neq \emptyset$.